# Can't turn-off uniform bucket-level

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to change the bucket level to detailed/not uniform, and after I execute the comand `gsutil uniformbucketlevelaccess set off gs://mybucket`, I recieve the message below:

> Disabling Uniform bucket-level access for gs://mybucket...
> BadRequestException: 400 Disabling uniform bucket-level access for bucket "mybucket" is not allowed after 90 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you switch to uniform bucket level access, and 90 days have passed since that action, it is no longer reversible, as the note in their [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access#overview) specifies.
Quoting the docs:

> Using this feature disables ACLs for all Cloud Storage resources: access to Cloud Storage resources then is granted exclusively through IAM. After you enable uniform bucket-level access, **you can reverse your decision for 90 days**.

If you want to use fine-grained access levels (ACLs), currently the only way is to create another bucket, and [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets) the contents to it.